# Wordpress comments not showing in single.php

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, comments

comments not showing in single.php

this is my code in single.php (I have created comments.php and copied the code from default comments.php file theme):

```
<?php get_header(); ?>


<div class="content-post container">

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

    <p><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> at <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?> | <?php the_category(', '); ?> | <?php comments_number('No comment', '1 comment', '% comments'); ?></p>

    <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php wp_list_comments(); ?>



    <?php endwhile; else: ?>

    <h2>Woops...</h2>

    <p>Sorry, no posts we're found.</p>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <p align="center"><?php posts_nav_link(); ?></p>

</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

could this be due the css issue? I also installed Disqus plugin and its not displaying

Comment: try change `wp_list_comments();` to `comments_template();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code looks good. Could be a couple things:

In the admin area, go to the post your viewing and find the "Comments Allowed" checkbox, if your theme allows it.

Try changing the code:

```
wp_list_comments();
```

to:

```
comments_template();
```

Change it back if that doesn't work.

Don't know what you mean by "css issue". If it's a CSS issue, make some comments, then view the page in a browser. View the page source, and if the comments are set to display:none, you'll still be able to see them in the page source, then you'll know if it's a CSS issue.